# Highlighting rendering as text

Tags: algolia

I have turned on highlighting in the Algolia admin console, and the terms in my search results are getting wrapped with "*" and "*", but they are showing up as plain text instead of being rendered as HTML. In other words if I search for "test" I see all instances of the word "test" wrapped in the tags instead of being rendered according to that tag's style.

My code to render the results is as follows:

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
         container: '#hits-container',
         templates: {
           empty: 'No results',
           item: '<strong><a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a></strong><br>{{type}}<br><i><span style="font-size: smaller !important;"{{_highlightResult.summary.value}}</span></i><br>'
         },
         hitsPerPage: 25
    })
);
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious.

Also - where can I find a reference to all of the possible variables I can use in the template code?  I'm not sure I understand the difference between those with two brackets vs those with three brackets.

Comment: The above striped out my EM tags.  I'm using the default highlighting tags in the Algolia config panel.

Comment: Per the information on this page (http://patternlab.io/docs/data-json-mustache.html) I think the answer is to use triple braces instead of double braces. But when I add the triple braces I get an error in line 35 of invariant.js which is being called automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighted result is stored in the _highlightResult attribute.
So instead of {{title}}, you can use {{{_highlightResult.title.value}}} and you will have the highlighted HTML value

Answer (score 2):

About your first question, I cannot find a reference to `invariant.js` in either `instantsearch.js` nor `hogan.js`, but it might be used in one of their dependencies. A stacktrace would help a lot.

However, there are already two things to change in your template:
You are right about the need of [triple braces to avoid escaping of HTML code](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Variables).
Your template also misses a closing `>`.

Often, when you have issues with a template, try writing it with indentation, it helps a lot quickly visualizing mistakes.

```js
'<strong>' +
'  <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">' +
'    {{title}}' +
'  </a>' +
'</strong>' +
'<br>' +
'{{type}}' +
'<br>' +
'<i>' +
'  <span style="font-size: smaller !important;"' + // Here a closing > is missing
'    {{_highlightResult.summary.value}}' + // Here you need to use triple braces
'  </span>' +
'</i>' +
'<br>'
```

To visualize all available properties, you can use the `transformData` parameter which is available on almost all `instantsearch.js`'s widgets (see "All options" tab [in the documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits)). It's usually used to modify the data just before passing it to the template, but can also be used to do some logging.

```js
instantsearch.widgets.hits({
     container: '#hits-container',
     transformData: {
       item: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
         return data;
       }
     }
     // Other options
});
```

With this, open your browser console and type a query to see what attributes the objects have.